# JavaScript quickSort errore

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

this is the algorithme i writed

```
var arr = [0,2,5,10,3,22,12,8,20];


let quickSort = (arr) => {
    if(arr.length === 1){
        return arr;
    };
    let len = arr.length;

    let pivot = Math.floor(arr.length / 2);
    
    const Rightarr = [];

    const Leftarr = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < len ; i++){
        if (arr[i] < pivot){
            Leftarr.push(arr[i]);
        }else{
            Rightarr.push(arr[i]);
        };
    };
    if(Leftarr.length > 0 && Rightarr > 0){
        console.log(...quickSort(Leftarr) , pivot , ...quickSort(Rightarr));
    }else if (Leftarr.length > 0 ){
        console.log(...quickSort(Leftarr),pivot);
    }else{
        console.log(pivot,...quickSort(Rightarr));
    };
    console.log(arr);
};

quickSort(arr);
```

and when i run this code , i saw this in console
**main.js:26 Uncaught TypeError: quickSort is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
at quickSort (main.js:26)
at main.js:33**

my question is why i get this warning , and how to fix it

Comment: Your `quickSort` function never returns anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your quicksort function doesn't return anything as @Ivar has pointed out.

Also, there are errors in your code

```
if(Leftarr.length > 0 && Rightarr > 0)
```

looks like it should be

```
if(Leftarr.length > 0 && Rightarr.length > 0)
```